# MESSAGE_DELIVERED FCM events not exported to BigQuery starting from 17-12-2019

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I have *Cloud Messaging* -> *BigQuery* integration enabled.

According to documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery), there are bunch of event types exported to it, including `MESSAGE_DELIVERED`. But the last date I got `MESSAGE_DELIVERED` events in table is Dec'17.

Interesting, that starting from Nov'30 I see new analytics event: `notification_receive`.

Is it a bug or undocumented changes?

[image: FCM events types vs notification_receive]

Answer (score 3):

Got response from firebase support:

> On December 17, 2019, we've made some changes to the data that is
>   exported to BigQuery from Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to improve
>   cross-platform consistency. Messages sent on or after December 17,
>   2019 will not include certain fields in the BigQuery export.
>
> Specifically, the following Android-only data will no longer be
>   exported: `device_recently_active` The following event types:
>
> ```
> MESSAGE_DELIVERED_ON_RECONNECT
> MESSAGE_EXPIRED
> MESSAGE_DELAYED_DOZE
> MESSAGE_COLLAPSED
> MESSAGE_DELAYED_THROTTLED
> DEVICE_NOT_FOUND
> MESSAGE_ACKED
> MESSAGE_DELIVERY_INTERNAL_ERROR
> ```

Comment: @Micheal 
Is there a workaround? Or do we never get the MESSAGE_DELIVERED event anymore ?

Comment: I'm using notification_receive right now. There is opt-in to enable message delivery data export on Android: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#enable-message-delivery-data-export-on-android, but I didn't try it